# Complicated curves intertwined in the link figures (I): Unsolved Christmas tree decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, technical-drawing, tikz-knots

I am struggled to draw these types of figures:

I guessed there is a package called the knot library (just learned this thing exist 2 mins ago):

[image]

So I am going to try the knot library out. But in case there are some useful advices, I am all ears to hear your input!!! Thank you!

> So my challenges for you are that: How to draw the above figure in tikz?

(p.s. I find these figures by random Googling on line. Which are similar to what I wish to draw in my mind, but not the same.)

Edit: I simplify the question.

Comment: I guess you will get a more concrete answer if you show what you really want. All this is straightforward with the knot library, I guess.

Comment: thanks! just precisely the same or similar figures like I posted. I am trying!