# Complicated curves intertwined in the link figures (II)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing, tikz-knots

This is a more advanced question following [an earlier one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466279/149730).

I am struggled to draw these types of figures:
[image]

There is a package called the knot library.

So I am going to try the knot library out. But in case there are some useful advices, I am all ears to hear your input!!! Thank you!

> So my challenges for you are that: How to draw the above figure in tikz?

Comment: -1 for no effort.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an attempt to precisely reproduce your picture, but just an alternative to `knots`. This is a way to have gaps when the left halves of the ellipse intersect with the dashed curves, and no gaps on the right halves. This way is described in the `knots` manual to some extent.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[arsty]{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\tikzset{arsty/.style={}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[red,very thick,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt,
->-/.list={0.0,0.2,0.4}] plot[smooth cycle,tension=2]
coordinates {(0,-0.2) (-1.7,-0.5) (0,-0.5) (1.7,-0.5) };
\draw[blue,very thick,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt,
->-/.list={0.42,0.75}] plot[smooth cycle,tension=1.8]
coordinates {(0,0) (2,-0.5) (0,-0.7) (-2,-0.5) };
\foreach \X in {-1.5,0,1.5}
{\draw[line width=1.6pt] (\X,-3.5) arc(-90:90:0.5 and 1.5);}
\draw[rounded corners=1.75cm,double=black,white,double distance=1.6pt,
line width=2.4pt] (-4,-2) rectangle (4,2);
\tikzset{arsty/.style={black,line width=1.6pt}}
\foreach \X in {-1.5,0,1.5}
{\draw[double=black,white,double distance=1.6pt,line width=2.4pt,->-=0.5]
(\X,-0.5) arc(90:270:0.5 and 1.5);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]